# How to display an image in flutter which is stored on Firebase Storage but it has a link which upon clicking downloads the image

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

```
final Model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getuser;
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoUrl),
),
```

The user is got from Firebase Auth. It has a property 'photoUrl' which is a link to the profile photo of the user stored in Firebase Storage.
When this link is clicked in the Firebase console, It directly downloads the image onto my computer.

The error I get using NetworkImage is:

> Failed to load network image.
> Image URL:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-66769.appspot.com/o/profilePics%2FoJKTbPWZHhPVeHjsXADJPCcSHb42?alt=media&token=7a450efa-345d-40b3-a57e-c0af81303fff

The above URL is what User.photoUrl provides.

What could I use other than NetworkImage?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to store the image URL like this.

```
final Reference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('folderName')
            .child("imageName with it's file extension");
await firebaseStorageRef.putData(await (yourimage as File/Xfile).readAsBytes());
final String? imageURL = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

And after that, you can use imageURL in `Image.network()` or any other Network image widget.

Also make sure you used File type or XFile type **yourimage** in the above code.

Comment: That's totally right, but the image stored there is a profile picture of the user which has been picked up from the gallery by the user at the time of User SignUp, it has random name.

Comment: Then you have to create download link using it's references. You can find out more from this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files#download_files).

Answer (score 0):

just upload the pic rightly and use the downloadUrl latter to display. Below is code snippet from my own project

```
static Future<String> uploadProfilePic(File file, String previousPicturePath) async {
    var storageRef = firebaseStorage().ref();

    var uniquePath = const Uuid().v4();

    Reference profilePicRef;

    if (previousPicturePath.isEmpty) {
       profilePicRef = storageRef.child("ProfilePics/$uniquePath");
    } else {
       profilePicRef = firebaseStorage().refFromURL(picturePath);
    }

    await profilePicRef.putFile(file);
    return profilePicRef.getDownloadURL();
}
```

so you will save the result of the method which is the download url in order to use latter to display the picture. no need to bother which type of image it is just using the downloadurl will display the picture in your chosen widget.